# How can i show an alert on press of a navigation back button but not when a simple button is pressed?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

when i press the back button of react native navigation , the alert is shown as expected but when i press the simple Button , i want to go back without showing the alert

heres my code

```
const EditTextScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
const [buttonClicked,setButtonClicked] = React.useState(false)

const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);


  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        const action = e.data.action;
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges && buttonClicked) {
          return;
        }

        e.preventDefault();

        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [hasUnsavedChanges,buttonClicked, navigation]
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus
        style={styles.input}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Type something…"
        onChangeText={setText}
      />
      <Button onPress={()=>{
        setButtonClicked(true)
        navigation.goBack()
      }}>confirm</Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

when the confirm button is pressed, the state is changed to true ,due to which user should be able to go back without getting the alert but i still get the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React state updates are processed asynchronously, so when the simple button is clicked ***both*** the `setButtonClicked(true)` to enqueue a state update ***and*** `navigation.goBack()` are basically called at the same time, the `beforeRemove` handler isn't going to know of or wait for the React state update to be processed.

You may be able to use a React ref here instead since they can be mutated at any time during the React component render cycle.

Example implementation:

```
const EditTextScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const buttonClickedRef = React.useref(false);

  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const beforeRemoveHandler = (e) => {
      const action = e.data.action;

      // Include check that simple button was clicked
      if (!hasUnsavedChanges && buttonClickedRef.current) {
        // Reset that simple button was clicked
        buttonClickedRef.current = false;

        return;
      }

      e.preventDefault();

      Alert.alert(
        'Discard changes?',
        'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
        [
          { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
          {
            text: 'Discard',
            style: 'destructive',
            onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
          },
        ]
      );
    }

    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', beforeRemoveHandler);

    // Return useEffect cleanup function to unsubscribe event listeners
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [hasUnsavedChanges, buttonClicked, navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus
        style={styles.input}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Type something…"
        onChangeText={setText}
      />
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          // Set true that simple button was clicked
          buttonClickedRef.current = true;
          navigation.goBack();
        }}
      >
        confirm
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```